# jquery call to javascript function that returns true returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery function that is triggered by a button click. When it then calls a javascript function that returns true however, jquery claims the value is undefined.

```
function mytrue()
{
  alert ("true is returned");
  return true;
}

$('#save').click(function() 
{
   var response = mytrue();
   if (response) { 
      alert ("This should work!");
   } else
   {
      alert ("This is puzzeling? "+response);
   }
}
```

I get the "true is returned" alert and the "This is puzzeling? undefined" alert.

Comment: Please read the FAQ and fix the formatting. It's completely wrong.

Comment: your question is even more puzzling. Please post full code.

Comment: [It works just fine.](http://jsfiddle.net/k5h52/)

Comment: Sorry the code is too much for this comment area and I don't have a public site for you to see it.

Comment: I've been racking my brains trying to figure this one out. Only the returns are undefined I could use a global variable and try it but that's not the point, it should work!!!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you just forgot the trailing `)` parenthesis after your `$('#save')...` function

Here is a link to a jsfiddle of your code that works: http://jsfiddle.net/ZswU8/

Comment: the } alone is a typo, it's actually }); for the $('#save') event

Comment: The alert message is just before the return true; and there are no other conditions or statements following that could change the result. It's the end of the function, I could try passing back a value other than true/false and see if that works. I thought it might be something related to how jquery and javascript handle true/false values.

Comment: function mytrue()
{
  alert ("OK is returned");
  return "OK";
}

$('#save').click(function() 
{
   var response = mytrue();
   if (response === "OK") { 
      alert ("This should work!");
   } else
   {
      alert ("This is puzzeling? "+response);
   }
});

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?  What browser are you testing this in?  Because the jsfiddle linked above works as intended... I'm not getting the same result as you.

Comment: chrome 19.0.1084.56 m
Firefox 13.0.1
IE 8

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm going to try another approach and include the function code in the click event, this should eliminate any value passing. I can't use jsfiddle because of the server side php calls in the mytrue function. (Can't fit all this code in a post)

Comment: This makes no sense, I changed the return from the javascript function  to a global variable assignment and it works.

Comment: Are you defining the `mytrue` function elsewhere accidentally?

Comment: I figured out why and part of it has to what I don't know. 
the jquery events were included in the document ready section while the javascript functions were outside the document ready function. This was done because of a conflict with the jquery UI for datepicker which uses $(function() { $("#fromdate" ).datepicker( {autoSize: true} ); $( "#todate" ).datepicker( {autoSize: true} ); }
Which is a general event handler, my work around for getting other functions to work was to separate them from the document ready function. I think the datepicker event handler is messing with function returns.

Comment: The consequences of using plugins is that you don't really know what they are doing.

Comment: Wrong answer. The function was returning a value just not before the jquery event handler moved on to the next statement. Now I just need to understand the proper syntax and parlance for what I need to do, which is ensure the vent handler waits for the function to return a value.

Comment: I don't think it's a race-case.  The `alert()` will halt your JavaScript code so the return of `mytrue()` should happen before your click-event handler runs its conditional on the result of `mytrue()`.  There must be more code that you're not including as the code above returns `true` as intended.  See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZswU8/) again for confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem I'm having. I know it's a scope thing, but I'm not sure how to get around it.

http://jsfiddle.net/k5h52/12/

```
var a = {
    mytrue:function()
    {
      alert ("true is returned");
      return true;
    }
}

var b = {
    init:function(){
        $('#save').click(function() 
    {
        var f = function(){a.mytrue()};

           var response = f();
           if (response) { 
              alert ("This should work!");
           } else
           {
              alert ("This is puzzeling? "+response);
           }
        });
    }
}

b.init();
```